# Linq to entity with dynamically growing where clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, where-clause, predicate

I am trying to fetch data from an entity based on some criteria. The WHERE clause will have any number of 'OR' conditions. How can I acheive this?

```cs
var skill = skillset.split(";"); //array can have any number of items
var EmployeeList1 = EmployeeList
   .Where(x => x.Primary1.ToUpper().Contains(skill[0])         
       || x.Primary2.ToUpper().Contains(skill[0])
       || x.Primary1.ToUpper().Contains(skill[1])                       
       || x.Primary2.ToUpper().Contains(skill[1]))
   .ToList();

return EmpMapper.Mapper.Map<List<EmployeeModel>>(EmployeeList1);
```

I need to build an expression for where clause with 'n' number of 'OR' conditions. I tried using predicate, but got exception(Index was outside the bounds of the array.).

```
    var predicate =  PredicateBuilder.New<ResourceEntity>(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < skill.Count(); i++)
    {
       predicate= predicate.Or(p => p.Primary1.Contains(skill[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy `for` variable into local variable:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<ResourceEntity>(true);
for (int i = 0; i < skill.Length; i++)
{
    var s = skill[i];
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Primary1.ToUpper().Contains(s));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Primary2.ToUpper().Contains(s));
}
```